# How to align an image using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an image using javascript in an HTML page, I want to lift the image on top of the line using the script, this is my script for the image alignment:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");

img.src="meme.jpg";
img.width=500;
img.height=500;
img.top=50;
img.alt='Meme';
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

This is how it looks now:
[image]

All I need is to make the image on top of the line a bit on the right.

Comment: img.style.top=50;img.style.position='absolute';